# Hash algorithms for load balancing

Tags: php, load-balancing

**IMPORTANT**: Before you suggest that we use a readily available load balancer, please understand that we're not trying to load balance normal internet traffic. We receive data from a number of sources, some of which aren't internet connected (ie they may use SMS, or similar). We process these and then forward the messages on to the next stage. It is this internal step that we need to load balance. **It is not using HTTP requests**

Now the scenario:

I'm doing some testing on various hashing algorithms in PHP to use for load balancing. I need to guarantee that every *device* is load balanced to the same node. In our use case, every message has a *serial number* which is constant, so I'm planning on using this value. It is critical that all messages from a given device are load balanced to the same node. We are not interested in the node capacity at this point.

So, I've read a few articles about using the modulus of a hash etc to determine which node to direct to. I've seen some stating that the decimal representation of a hash from MD5, SHA1, SHA256 and SHA512 will all exceed the `PHP_INT_MAX` therefore the modulus will always be zero, so we can't use that to load balance.

I've also seen suggestions that we could simply bit shift away a chunk of the hash and use only the high bits to get the modulus and again, use that.

This got me wondering... Since we only need to load balance between a relatively small number of nodes to begin (it won't exceed 16 for some time), are any algorithms adequate that we could just use the first byte and load balance based on that?

So I wrote this really simple function:

```
function balanceToNode(string $serial, string $algo="md5", int $nodes=1)
{
    $hash = hash($algo, $serial);
    return hexdec($hash[1]) % $nodes;
}
```

I ran this with `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256` and `sha512` against a sample of 1000 real serial numbers from our database. I tested each with 4, 8 and 16 nodes and examined the standard deviation across each of the nodes.

## Single Byte Test

What I found was that using `md5` resulted in predictable and well balanced data between the nodes, regardless of how many nodes we used. `sha1` balanced poorly if we had a small number of nodes, but balanced better with a larger number of nodes. `sha256` was even worse than `sha1` but still balanced better with more nodes, and `sha512` was almost unaffected by the number of nodes but still didn't balance as well as `md5`.

Here is the actual data that we got from the tests. We took an estimated standard deviation from the sample to get to the numbers per node, and then the stdev of the population to get a figure for the algorithm consistency. I may be doing maths wrong! I'm looking for smaller numbers in all cases

### MD5

- 4 nodes: 8.041558721
- 8 nodes: 7.171371656
- 16 nodes: 7.554248253

Consistency: 0.356104153

### SHA1

- 4 nodes: 17.53092506
- 8 nodes: 13.24494513
- 16 nodes: 7.966596931

Consistency: 3.91162024

### SHA256

- 4 nodes: 25.81988897
- 8 nodes: 15.7116881
- 16 nodes: 11.40741718

Consistency: 6.040803998

### SHA512

- 4 nodes: 11.5758369
- 8 nodes: 10.87592361
- 16 nodes: 9.535897091

Consistency: 0.846358482

## 8 Byte Test

I ran the test again, this time using the first 8 bytes from any given hash. This made a massive difference, although `md5` still appears to perform the best. The big surprise for me here is that `sha512` performed significantly worse with 16 than with 8

### MD5

- 4 nodes: 18
- 8 nodes: 13.53302838
- 16 nodes: 7.916228058

Consistency: 4.12559407

### SHA1

- 4 nodes: 27.41046029
- 8 nodes: 17.63114128
- 16 nodes: 8.181279444

Consistency: 7.850664268

### SHA256

- 4 nodes: 25.31139401
- 8 nodes: 15.25029274
- 16 nodes: 7.509993342

Consistency: 7.287949408

#### SHA512

- 4 nodes: 17.60681686
- 8 nodes: 6.886840453
- 16 nodes: 11.44261042

Consistency: 4.39280188

## My Actual Question

Bearing in mind that we're using the hash algorithm PURELY to distribute messages across a cluster of nodes, and not to secure passwords. Also, based on the samples, the questions are:

1. Am I safe to use the first byte only?
2. Is it OK to use `md5`
3. Am I doing maths wrong?

Comment: Most load balancers will let you map all requests from a given client to a single backend server. You should probably select a load balancer and read the documentation for it.

Comment: Not practical in our case; the clients are our own receivers and the devices are not typical web browsers. They don't have consistent IPs, don't support cookies... some aren't even IP connected devices. We receive them, process the message and then forward it on to the next step, which is what we're trying to load balance here

Comment: So they're you're receivers? Are you not able to manipulate the requests to something predictable, like a X-DEVICE-ID header or similar? Honestly I wouldn't implement this logic in PHP, it's bound to be slow.

Comment: The scenario is thousands (potentially millions) of devices that dial into receiver software, sometimes over the internet, sometimes not. Every device reports back a serial number. Using these serial numbers I want to load balance into the next stage, which is currently a single instance. I'm only using PHP for testing some maths as it's ideal for prototyping due to rapid development that it enables

Comment: How is the serial number passed?

Comment: From the receiver to the next stage? It's in a JSON payload. I'd put it in the header though so that the load balancing solution doesn't need to process the message body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101691/discussion-between-ant-the-knee-and-quickshiftin).

Answer (score 0):

If your serial numbers have uniform random distribution, use

n = serial % N

where n is the node to address and N is the total number of nodes.

With more serials in use, the load may be better balanced by using some middle bits rather than the lowest bits how this simple formula does. CPU caches often operate this way. But this additional complexity may or may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Serials don't have uniform random distribution. Nor do we have any control over them. That's why I was trying a hash

Comment: Then check the simple, easy to compute things (CRC32, Adler and the like) first. Using cryptography just for a hashcode seems somewhat overkill. We need randomness, not security.

Comment: That's why we looked at MD5 and SHA1 first; fast checksum hashes. Can try CRC too, see if that gives adequate distribution.

Comment: Oh, and for the record, I would never, in a million years, lump MD5 or SHA1 in the "cryptography" bucket